# need help installing pecl on centos 5.8

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, pecl, yum

So basically I'm trying to install APC, but I can't get pecl to work on Centos 5.8 i686

I have the latest stable releases of php-fpm, mysql, and nginx. Everything is working at 100%, everything is smooth. I'm running a live website with no problems. I just can't pecl to work.

[image: yum install pcl]

yum install php-pear:
[image]

Most of the packages I'm trying to instal have dependency issues with php-common (whatever that is).

```
php-common = 5.1.6-32.el5 is needed
```

Much help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

`/usr/bin/pecl` is available from `php-pear` package.

The dependency failures you got are stange. Probably because you have mixed installation of `php-*` 5.1 RPMs and `php53-*` 5.3 RPMs and get conflicts on devel files. You should do some clean up to keep only one set of RPMs for your target version, either 5.1 or 5.3.

You also have to install `gcc`, `httpd-devel`, `php(53)-devel` and finally `php-pear` to get `phpize` working.

Then you should be able to run `pecl install apc`

Answer (score 0):

First of all assure you have your distro updated, you can do it with

> yum update

Then check if you are not using any third-party repo, that contains this packages.
If you can, remove all the php packages with

> yum remove php*

and try to install them again.

If you can't solve it, try the [Fedora EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repositories which provides some updated packages.

**All the commands needs be run by root.**

Comment: Just remember if you have anything you're running like *php-pdo* or something like that you'll need to reinstall that as well. I ran these commands and hosed my install. Took me a bit to get back to where I was.